# custom filter not working in android

Tags: android, filter

I have implemented custom filter in list but not working, can some body tell me where is the problem in my code ??

this is my on create method .

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testsample);

    sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);


    item_list = (ArrayList<Item_Category>) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

    if (item_list == null) {
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setChoiceMode(lv.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        item_list = new ArrayList<Item_Category>();

        item_list.add(new Item_Category("gold", false));
        item_list.add(new Item_Category("sugar", false));
        item_list.add(new Item_Category("gulli", false));
        item_list.add(new Item_Category("silver", false));
        item_list.add(new Item_Category("chmacham", false));


        arrayList = new ArrayList<Item_Category>();

        arrayList.addAll(item_list);
        arrayAdapter = new ItemCategoryArrayAdapter(this, arrayList);

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {



            selected = text.trim();

            //lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            if (arrayAdapter != null) {
                arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(selected);
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

this is all for custom list view and for custom filter..

```
  private class Item_Category
{

    String category_Name ;
    boolean checked ;

    public String getCategory_Name() {
        return category_Name;
    }

    public void setCategory_Name(String category_Name) {
        this.category_Name = category_Name;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public Item_Category(String category_Name, boolean checked) {
        this.category_Name = category_Name;
        this.checked = checked;
    }



}

private static class Item_Category_ViewHolder
{
    TextView categoryName;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public TextView getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(TextView categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public CheckBox getCheckBox() {
        return checkBox;
    }

    public void setCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox) {
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
    }


    public Item_Category_ViewHolder(TextView categoryName, CheckBox checkBox) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
    }
}


public class ItemCategoryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item_Category> implements Filterable {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<String> itemList;
    List<Item_Category> filtered;
    List<Item_Category> mStringFilterList;
    ItemCategoryFilter categoryFilter;

    public ItemCategoryArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Item_Category> categoryList) {
        super(context, R.layout.everyday_item_category_row, R.id.itemName, categoryList);
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.

        filtered = new ArrayList<Item_Category>(categoryList);
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mStringFilterList = new ArrayList<Item_Category>(categoryList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Planet to display
        Item_Category item_list = (Item_Category) this.getItem(position);

        // The child views in each row.
        CheckBox checkBox;
        TextView itemCategory;

        // Create a new row view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.everyday_item_category_row, null);

            // Find the child views.
            itemCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);

            // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't have to
            // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
            convertView.setTag(new Item_Category_ViewHolder(itemCategory, checkBox));

            // If CheckBox is toggled, update the planet it is tagged with.
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    Item_Category item_list1 = (Item_Category) cb.getTag();
                    item_list1.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        }
        // Reuse existing row view
        else {
            // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call findViewById().
            Item_Category_ViewHolder viewHolder = (Item_Category_ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
            itemCategory = viewHolder.getCategoryName();

        }

        // Tag the CheckBox with the Planet it is displaying, so that we can
        // access the planet in onClick() when the CheckBox is toggled.
        checkBox.setTag(item_list);

        // Display planet data
        checkBox.setChecked(item_list.isChecked());
        itemCategory.setText(item_list.getCategory_Name());

        CheckBox c1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
        final TextView t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        c1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                if (isChecked) {
                    itemList.add(t1.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    if (itemList.contains(t1.getText().toString())) {
                        itemList.remove(t1.getText().toString());
                    }

                }
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (categoryFilter == null)
            categoryFilter = new ItemCategoryFilter();

        return categoryFilter;
    }


    private class ItemCategoryFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            mStringFilterList = new ArrayList<Item_Category>();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Item_Category> filterList = new ArrayList<Item_Category>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getCategory_Name().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        Item_Category itemCategory = new Item_Category(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getCategory_Name(), false);

                        filterList.add(itemCategory);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            filtered = (ArrayList<Item_Category>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is the problem that you faced of ?

Comment: Can you please show the error log or tell us what is happening?

Comment: my custom filter is not filtering (Textview ) in the listview

Answer (score 1):

Creating an Adapter to a Custom grid view or list view, both have some problems in filtering. You see that, the adapters won't filter the data in your grid or list views.

I can't paste code, but I would recommend you to take a look at implementation of `ArrayAdapter.class`. Make sure that `ItemCategoryArrayAdapter.class` has most of the methods present in `ArrayAdapter.class`.

Just make sure most of the methods present in `ArrayAdapter.class` are implemented in `ItemCategoryArrayAdapter.class`.

This will fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Change your adapter constructor as follows.

```
    public ItemCategoryArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Item_Category> categoryList) {
     filtered = new ArrayList<Item_Category>(categoryList);
    super(context, R.layout.everyday_item_category_row, R.id.itemName, filtered);
    // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
```

You are passing the complete list ie categoryList instead of filtered List and hence it is not reflecting.

Comment: i have tried after removing lv.setAdapter () still not working .the problem is - filter is not filtering the content in the listview .

Comment: I have changed my answer. Try with this and let me know if it works.

Comment: sorry not working , as far as i know  we can not initialize any thing before super keyword .

Comment: Super must be first statement in the method

Comment: Hi any one is here who can answer my question please .